# Override Vuetify styling with .less file

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, less, vuetify.js

I am in the middle of developing an app based on Vue and Vuetify. So far, the library proved to be largely helpful in quickly prototyping new features. But now I have to align the styling in the app to the already specified styling, already done in ".less" files.

I know that it's possible to override SASS variables of Vuetify, but that would mean that every time something changes in the external styling I have to align with, I would need to modify the variables. That's not really what I'm after, as I would like to integrate the two as smoothly as possible.

I've managed to load the LESS files into the app, but the styling always gets overridden with the Vuetify styles. Has anybody encountered a problem like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you should check is, when your `.less` files are loaded. If you want to overwrite the Vuetify styling, then your `.less` file has to be loaded after the Vuetify styling.

The second thing is, there may be some Vuetify stylings which are using the `!important` rule. This will automatically overwrite your styling, if it's not laoded after the Vuetify styling and also includes the `!important` rule.

Last but not least, if the Vuetify stylings don't use the `!important` rule, you can think about using it to overwrite the Vuetify styling yourself. But bare in mind, that you should prevent using `!important` anywhere you can. It should only be used, if there really is no other option to solve a problem.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens. The .less files are loaded and are working, but some of the Vuetify stylings have !important rules, which overrite them. None of my stylings use the !important, as I know it's not a good practice to use them.

I was just wondering if there's some way to override styling done by Vuetify, by other means than modifying SASS variables one by one. If not, I guess I should think about dropping Vuetify, as modifying components to suit my needs gets harder and harder.

Comment: @maleficca well if Vuetify is using `!important` and you don't, I am afraid that you will not be able to overwrite the stylings you want.